# Searching for a pipeline/workflow software

Tags: jenkins, automation, devops, workflow, pipeline

I am currently looking for a free pipeline/workflow software that can help me with the following task.

The following steps have to be executed one after the other:

```
1. connect to a Windows server and issue a command. (Powershell script    on the Windows server, triggered e.g. by Powershell remoting).
2. wait until the command is finished, then move the data to the source server (can be done via file-share and a bash script on the linux server)
3. on this linux server the data must be unpacked and processed (takes several hours) (bash command)
4. these processed data must then be imported into a database also on the linux server (also takes several hours) (bash script)
5. after the import process, several queries have to be run on the database and the results have to be written to a CSV file. (bash commands)
6. done :)
```

For the individual steps I have already written scripts (see above), which perform the respective step automatically. What I am looking for now is a software to control and monitor the execution of the scripts. So that these steps are started in the correct order and if there is an error in one of the steps the whole workflow stops and I can see where something went wrong.

So first idea I had thought of something like Jenkins. However, I'm not sure if this can work or if this is not a bit much overload for such a simple workflow, since Jenkins goes more in the CI/CD direction...

Does anyone give me an idea or a software that would fit this use case well?

Thanks